# Конвертация 3D моделей в XAML

Tags: xaml, 3d

Имеется порядка 30-ти 3D моделей, нарисованных в 3DMax (соответственно исходный формат любой, поддерживаемый в 3DMax: .max, .3ds и т.д.).

Требуется конвертировать данные 3D модели в XAML разметку, желательно, в виде статических ресурсов.

Какими бесплатными средствами (программы, скрипты, плагины и т.д.) проще всего осуществить конвертацию и получить наилучший результат?

Answer (score 2):

Задача не из простых, но решение имеется: [3d model to WPF](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/maxim/archive/2009/03/31/daily-tip-how-to-import-3d-model-to-wpf-from-3d-max.aspx)