# 3D модели в Android

Tags: android, 3d

Здравствуйте!
Столкнулся с проблемой в имплантации *3D(Например .max (Можно и другой)*)в `Android app`

---

***Задача состоит в:***
 - В обычный *layer-layout* (слой-макет) внедрить довольно сложную модель
(Это не куб, а допустим *Ветвистое Дерево*)
 - Проиграть некую анимацию (Допустим *Содрогание листьев*)

---

Есть некие ограничения, которые не позволяют сделать это через тот же ***Unity***
Перелистал уже все ресурсы (на разных языках) - ничего схожего не нашел...кроме

- [7-летней статьи про "Конвертацию 3D моделей в XAML"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/662/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-3d-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B2-xaml)
- [5-летней статьи на Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/144955/) - *которую я перечитывал 20 раз и ничего кроме глобальной логики не понял*

*Подмогните/подскажите* - может кто-то сталкивался с таким... может у кого мысли какие есть - ***Буду очень признателен!***

Comment: Возможно вам подойдёт вариант, записать видео с анимацией и проигрывать его в приложении.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал использовать libGDX для загрузки и рендеринга 3d объектов.
Движок легко импортировать в свой проект и довольно просто с ним работать.

LibGDX имеет умеет работать с форматом .obj, а так же имеет собственный формат 3d моделей g3db, в который можно сконвертировать файл .fbx с помощью утилиты fbx-converter. Можно и так .max  -> .fbx -> .g3db. 
Есть хороший туториал по 3d https://xoppa.github.io/blog/loading-models-using-libgdx/ 

 
Так же движок умеет проигрывать и сводить анимации.

LibGDX можно встроить в проект как отдельное представление - SurfaceView. Не обязательно писать весть проект на нем.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите [на этот репо](https://github.com/andresoviedo/android-3D-model-viewer)

Умеет загружать 3D модели в формате OBJ и STL.

Не уверен, что умеет делать анимацию, но загружает объекты и рендерит очень хорошо.

3D Studio насколько я помню умеет конвертировать свои 3D модели в формат STL.

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое решение - нагенерить спрайтов. Массив png картинок содержащих ваше дерево, затем проиграть его как анимацию.
Это дешево, просто, нересурсоемко.

Использовать модель - несравнимо более сложное решение.
Могу посоветовать 3D движки из списка
[Android Arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/2?sort=created), чтобы найти подходйщий.

Рекомендую начать с [Rajawali](https://github.com/Rajawali/Rajawali)